# Regex: Match every occurrence of dash in between two specific symbols

Tags: regex

I have this string: `](-test-word-another)`

I'm trying to find every single occurrence of `-` in between `]` and `)`
Basically the return should be: ](`-`test`-`word`-`another)

Currently I have `(?<=\]\()(-)(?=\))` but that just finds if there is only one `-`

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the programming language/regex flavor?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using typescript

Comment: Do you need to replace them? `text.replace(/]\([^()]*\)/g, (x) => x.replace(/-/g, '_'))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I do need to replace `-` with `_` but how does the following `/\]\([^()]*\)/g` find it?

Comment: `/]\([^()]*\)/g` finds `](...)` and then `(x) => x.replace(/-/g, '_')` replaces each `-` inside each match

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah I see, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `/(?<=\].*)-(?=.*\))/gm`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/xkmTZs/3

This basically matches all `-` only if they occur after a `]` and before `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
text.replace(/]\([^()]*\)/g, (x) => x.replace(/-/g, '_'))
```

See the demo below:

```js
const text = 'Word-word ](-test-word-another) text-text-.';
console.log( text.replace(/]\([^()]*\)/g, (x) => x.replace(/-/g, '_')) );
```

The `]\([^()]*\)` regex matches a `](` substring, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`, and then all `-` chars inside the match value (`x` here) are replaced with `_` using `(x) => x.replace(/-/g, '_')`.

Another, single regex solution can look like

```
(?<=]\((?:(?!]\()[^)])*)-(?=[^()]*\))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkmTZs/2). It matches any `-` that is immediately preceded with `](` and any zero or more chars other than `)` that does not start a `](` char sequence, and is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.